# Why does Javascript addEventListener change scope of object pointer?

Tags: javascript, events

I am having some trouble with a fairly simple piece of vanilla Javascript. All it does, is get all p elements by their tag name, and attach an event handler to each one, which calls a function that changes the colour to red.

Outside the callback function `el` refers to the correct element, 1-6. But inside the loop, it always refers to the last one, despite javascript's lexical variable scoping nature. Why is this, and what can be done to implement indended behaviour?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7j4bg68g/

```
<p>1 This is a test.</p>
<p>2 This is a test.</p>
<p>3 This is a test.</p>
<p>4 This is a test.</p>
<p>5 This is a test.</p>
<p>6 This is a test.</p>
```

...

```
function takeAction() {
  this.style.color = 'red';
}

var els = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var el = els[i];

  // logs els 1 to 6 as expected.
  console.log(el.innerHTML);

  el.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // logs "6 This is a test.", and makes the last <p> tag red,
    // regardless of which <p> element you click on.
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
    takeAction.call(el);

  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Though not addressing the cause of the problem in your question, you could simplify the code and prevent the problem by simply changing the loop body to `els[i].addEventListener("click", takeAction)`

Answer (score 1):

This is because of closure, in your code you are referencing to "el". All the event handlers are having a reference to the same variable el which has changed to the last value it was given in the loop.
Try this,

```
function takeAction() {
  this.style.color = 'red';
}

var els = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var el = els[i];

  // logs els 1 to 6 as expected.
  console.log(el.innerHTML);
(function(elem){
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // logs "6 This is a test.", and makes the last <p> tag red, regardless of which <p> element you click on.
    console.log(elem.innerHTML); // logs "6 This is a test."
    takeAction.call(elem);

  }, false);
})(el);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to fix your syntax. It'll error right now. And while the corrected code would be a possible solution to the problem as presented, it's an unnecessarily verbose solution since the OP could simply use `this` inside the event handler.

Comment: This works: `el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
      takeAction.call(this);
     }, false);`

Comment: IceBox: You edited the question, but there's still a syntax error. Did you test your code?

Comment: @squint, sorry it was supposed to be a self executing function missed the round brackets